# Spring Integration Graceful Shutdown with TaskExecutor

Tags: spring-integration, graceful-shutdown

I have a Spring Boot web application which shuts down gracefully after a timeout of 120secs.
Recently we have added a Spring Integration Flow to the same application to be able to process some files from a directory. 
The poller uses a TaskExecutor to process files in multiple threads (5 for now).

```
public TaskExecutor chunkExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    taskExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(120);
    taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("customExecutor-");
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

PollerSpec looks like:

```
public void accept(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec) {
    sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(fixedDelay)
            .taskExecutor(chunkExecutor)
            .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)
            .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSyncFactory)
            .transactional(new PseudoTransactionManager()));
}
```

[image]

We have noticed that the Spring Integration flow does not follow the graceful shutdown of the main application.
In some instances, the poller even picks up files after the tomcat is shutdown.

If we don't use the taskExecutor, flow looks good

Is there anything else I need to do to make this Spring Integration flow shutdown gracefully like the main Spring Boot application while using the taskExecutor?

Update: 
Based on Artem's answer on TaskScheduling, I commented out the taskExecutor in the poller spec and added the scheduling properties.

However I noticed that there is only one thread running at any point in time even though the pool size is 2. Am I missing something?

Updated spec:

```
spring:
  task:
    scheduling:
      thread-name-prefix: "customScheduling-"
      pool:
        size: 2
      shutdown:
        await-termination-period: "120s"
        await-termination: true
```

PollerSpec:

```
    public void accept(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec) {
    sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(fixedDelay)
            //.taskExecutor(chunkExecutor)
            .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)
            .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSyncFactory)
            .transactional(new PseudoTransactionManager()));
}
```

From the logs I noticed that the tomcat has already shutdown while the scheduler is waiting for a REST call to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Artem mentioned, the shutdown was really for the tomcat and not for the async tasks. I was able to have a graceful shutdown of the executor by implementing an `EventListener` for `onContextClosedEvent` and call the `shutDown` on the `taskExecutor`. This invokes the graceful shutdown of the `taskExecutor`

```
@EventListener
public void onContextClosedEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
    taskExecutor.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Inbound Channel Adapter in Spring Integration is based on the `TaskScheduler` for its polling logic. So, you may look into its respective customization like you did for an executor: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.task-execution-and-scheduling

See `spring.task.scheduling.shutdown` properties.

The "graceful shutdown"  in Spring Boot, you mention, is really only for Tomcat. It knows nothing about other async processes in your application.

Comment: Updated my question based on the feedback from Artem.

Comment: The single thread is used from `TaskScheduler` because of `Pollers.fixedDelay`. That means start a new task when the previous one has been finished. The Tomcat threads has nothing to do with `TaskScheduler`. So, even if it is stopped, it does not interfere with `TaskScheduler` .

Comment: I changed it to `Pollers.fixedRate` but still see them processed sequentially.

Comment: Also, post the Tomcat shuts down, the Integration flow also starts shutdown. I have a REST call which is made from one of the handlers which then forwards the response to another handler. Post the rest call completion, the flow does not move to the next handler. Instead I get an error.

Comment: Error: `ERROR [customScheduling-2] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler: Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: A bean definition with name 'errorChannel' exists, but failed to be created; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'errorChannel': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)`

Comment: Any chances you can share a simple project to let us reproduce the problem on our side? The `SourcePolingChannelAdapter` must be stopped at the point and should not emit any new messages via scheduling.

Comment: Sure, let me prepare one and upload it to Github this week.

Comment: Artem: I was able to resolve the issue using an Event Listener (`onContextClosedEvent`) for the `TaskExecutor`. I removed the scheduling properties and the shutdown works fine. However, the executor runs for the full period of the shutdown. I do see some exceptions: `o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler: Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@67704d85[Shutting down..]`

Comment: Yeah... I still would like to see some sample to be able to reproduce and play with. Right now I struggle to come up with an idea how is the supposed to be. Thanks